# Numerical Integration in MatLab

Tags: matlab, numeric, numerical-integration

I am trying to compute an integral using Matlab's `dblquad`. To do it I first wrote a script function. My code is

```
function z = IntRect(x, y)
%The variables
z0=20;
x0=15;
y0=20;
rl=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+(z0/2)^2);
theta=acos(z0./(2*rl));
phi=atan(y./x);
%The function
z=(x0-z0*tan(theta).*cos(phi))*(y0-z0*tan(theta).*sin(phi))*(z0/2)^4;
z=z/rl.^3;
```

To compute the numerical integral I type in command window

```
z0=20;x0=15;y0=20;
Q = dblquad(@IntRect,0,x0/2,0,y0/2,1.e-6);
```

I get an error saying that

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> IntRect at 8
z=(x0-z0*tan(theta).*cos(phi))*(y0-z0*tan(theta).*sin(phi))*(z0/2)^4;

Error in ==> quad at 77
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in ==> dblquad>innerintegral at 84
    Q(i) = quadf(intfcn, xmin, xmax, tol, trace, y(i), varargin{:});

Error in ==> quad at 77
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in ==> dblquad at 60
Q = quadf(@innerintegral, ymin, ymax, tol, trace, intfcn, ...
```

What am I doing wrong with that?

**EDIT**

Replacing

```
z=(x0-z0*tan(theta).*cos(phi))*(y0-z0*tan(theta).*sin(phi))*(z0/2)^4;
```

with

```
z=(x0-z0*tan(theta).*cos(phi)).*(y0-z0*tan(theta).*sin(phi))*(z0/2)^4;
```

I get an new error

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> quad at 85
if ~isfinite(y(7))

Error in ==> dblquad>innerintegral at 84
    Q(i) = quadf(intfcn, xmin, xmax, tol, trace, y(i), varargin{:});

Error in ==> quad at 77
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in ==> dblquad at 60
Q = quadf(@innerintegral, ymin, ymax, tol, trace, intfcn, ...
```

Comment: Start debugging. What are the dimensions of the variables in line #8 where the first error occurs?

Comment: @Schorsch: thank you very much for your comment. That is something that I am not sure of... I know that the proble is somewhere in `theta` and `phi` variable but I cannot determine. What I know is that the have exaclty the same dimensions. So I used `phi'` instead of `phi` at line #8 but I get exactly the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help for `dblquad` says, the input `x` is a vector and `y` is a scalar and the output `z` is also vector. Thus anything in your integrand function that is a function of `x` will be a vector (e.g., `rl`) and you'll need to be careful to use element-wise operators where appropriate. You did not do this for the very last line.

Also, consider passing your initial value parameters via function handle rather than duplicating them inside the integrand function:

```
function dblquadtest
z0 = 20; x0 = 15; y0 = 20;
f = @(x,y)IntRect(x,y,x0,y0,z0);
Q = dblquad(f,0,x0/2,0,y0/2); % 1e-6 is the default tolerance

function z = IntRect(x, y, x0, y0, z0)
%The variables
rl=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+(z0/2)^2);
theta=acos(z0./(2*rl));
phi=atan(y./x);
%The function
z=(x0-z0*tan(theta).*cos(phi)).*(y0-z0*tan(theta).*sin(phi))*(z0/2)^4;
z=z./rl.^3;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! It works! It was the last line as you indicated thank you very much! However I didn't quite understand the part about passing the initial values via handle function. Are you implying to create a new function `dblquadtest` and run this function in the command prompt?

Comment: It's exactly what I'm doing with variable `f` in my answer above. Specifically `f` is an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) where `x` and `y` are passed in by `dblquad` as it runs and the others are passed in once when `f` is created. one can create anonymous functions in M-files or in the Matlab command window.

Answer (score 2):

You need an element-wise operator

```
z=(x0-z0*tan(theta).*cos(phi)).*(y0-z0*tan(theta).*sin(phi))*(z0/2)^4;
                              ^
                              |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The dimension error indeed dissapears, but I still cannot compute the intrgral. The error showing up says. Please check my updated question for the error. Thank's!

Comment: @Thanos - please update the question accordingly, it is impossible to read the comment. You might want to consider a new question for the new issue...